# Is "usually" placed correctly here?

Tags: word-order, idiomatic-language

"*I've never been here before. Do you know the coffee house just down the street? Usually that's where I go after work. You should join me someday.*"

Is "usually" placed naturally here?

Comment: Welcome to the ELL Stack Exchange, nazrathj! Can you indicate why you suspect this placement might be unnatural? Also, what research have you done to try to find the answer to your question?

Comment: It looks perfectly natural to me—I frequently (although certainly not always) use that particular diction. However, I would put a comma after the word, since it's being used to modify the entire sentence. *Usually, I only drink one or two beers when I go out.*

Answer (score -1):

No, I would say it is not natural.

The natural position is

> That's where I usually go after work.

Your sentence

> Usually that's where I go after work

puts emphasis on "Usually", and leaves me expecting something like "but last night I went to the other one".

Comment: Don't these sentences differ at least slightly?

Comment: Yes. As I said, putting _usually_ first _usually_ what the sentence is about.